# Calling a double condition on data in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, vector, reference, subset

I am trying to create two vectors of the 20th and 80th percentiles of monthly return data for companies from 1927 to 2013. The issue I have encountered is that in my nested four loop I don't know how to reference both the month and the year (i.e. the returns across all companies in April 1945). Right now the code looks like this:

```
qunatile<-function(r){
  vec20<-c(rep(0,1038))
  vec80<-c(rep(0,1038))
  for(i in 1927:2013){
    for(j in 1:12){
      vec20[j+12(i-1927)]<-quantile(r$(i, j),20)
      vec80[j+12(i-1927)]<-quantile(r$(i, j),80)
    }
  }
  data1decilest<-rbind(ps1NYSE,vec20,vec80)
}
```

But I know that that r$(i, j) notation is not correct. I was wondering if anyone knew how to do what I am attempting with that clearly incorrect code (i.e. reference all returns from a given month in a given year.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One option that would eliminate nesting loops is to create a column in your dataframe that contains a month/year combo (e.g. "Jan1955", "Apr1999", etc.) and then split your dataframe on that variable, and apply quantile functions. It's hard to say if this is solving your problem since there is not a reproducible example.  I assume here your data is called `df` and contains a `date` and a `value` column.

```
library(lubridate)
library(plyr)
df$newtime <- paste0(month(df$date, label = T, abbr = T), year(df$date))
q20 <- function(df){ quantile(df$value, 20) }
q80 <- function(df){ quantile(df$value, 80) }
vec20 <- ddply(df, .(newtime), FUN=q20)
vec80 <- ddply(df, .(newtime), FUN=q80
```